# How to correctly import python module and resolve "No module named error"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

[image]**The Situation:**

I am trying to import test.py subfolder1/file1.py

**The File Structure:**

```
Project folder
   |project subfolder
      |subfolder1
        |file1.py
      |subfolder2
         |pythonfile.py
      |test.py
```

**The Code I have used:**

```py
    import os
    import sys
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/..")
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    import test as t
```

**The Problem:**

This code above is returning the error:

```
'No module named 'test''
```

**The Question:**

How can I correctly import the module and avoid this error?

Comment: what if you simply `sys.path.append('..')`?

Answer (score 0):

When you import modules it's better to use absolute paths

```
import os
import sys
from Projectfolder.projectsubfolder.test as t
```

Remember that you may need to create empty `__init__.py` files for project_folder and project_subfolder folders

Comment: thanks for quick reply ..still i am getting same error

Comment: i have created __init__.py  file both project and sub folder

Comment: try: `import project_folder.project_subfolder.test as t`

Comment: still i am getting same error ..please find attachment

Comment: From screenshot. You should create empty `__init__.py` file in `Projectfolder`

Comment: i have created __init__.py file Projectfolder. PFA,still i am getting error